# Two writes using python logging

Tags: python, class, logging

I have two files of classes with essentially the same set up of logging:

```
"""code - of 1 class the parent with mods from Reut's answer"""
logger = None
def __init__(self, verboseLevel=4):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''    
    loggingLevels={1: logging.DEBUG,
               2: logging.INFO,
               3: logging.WARNING,
               4: logging.ERROR,
               5: logging.CRITICAL}

    #debug(), info(), warning(), error(), critical()
    if not tdoa.logger:
        tdoa.logger=logging.getLogger('TDOA')
        if (verboseLevel in range(1,6)):
            logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s',level=loggingLevels[verboseLevel])
        else:
            logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)
            tdoa.logger.critical("Incorrect logging level specified!")
    self.logger = tdoa.logger
    self.logger.debug("TDOA calculator using Newton's method.")
    self.verboseLevel = verboseLevel


    """code of second "subclass" (with Reut's changes) (who's function is printing twice):"""


def  __init__(self, verboseLevel=1, numberOfBytes=2, filename='myfile.log', ipaddr='127.0.0.1',getelset= True):
    #debug(), info(), warning(), error(), critical()
    # go through all this to know that only one logger is instantiated per class
    # Set debug level
    # set up various handlers (remove Std_err one for deployment unless you want them going to screen
    # create console handler with a higher log level
    if not capture.logger:
        capture.logger=logging.getLogger('SatGeo')
        console = logging.StreamHandler()

        if (verboseLevel in range(1,6)):
            console.setLevel(self.loggingLevels[verboseLevel])
            logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s',level=self.loggingLevels[verboseLevel],
                                filename=filename,filemode='a') #format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s'
        else:
            logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG,
                                filename=filename,filemod='a')
            console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            capture.logger.critical("Incorrect logging level specified!")

        # create formatter and add it to the handlers
        #formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        #console.setFormatter(formatter)
        # add the handlers to logger
        handlers=capture.logger.handlers
        if (console not in handlers):
            capture.logger.addHandler(console)
        else:
            capture.logger.critical("not adding handler")

    self.logger=capture.logger
```

I have a function in the "called class (satgeo)" that 'writes' to the logger:

```
def printMyself(self, rowDict):
    ii=1
    for res in rowDict:
        self.logger.critical('{0}************************************'.format(ii))
        ii+=1
        for key, value in res.items():
            self.logger.critical(' Name: {0}\t\t Value:{1}'.format(key, value))
```

When I call it by itself I get one output per `self.logger` call; but when I call it from the tdoa class it writes TWICE:
for example:

```
 Name: actualLat         Value:36.455444
 Name: actualLat         Value:36.455444
```

Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Are you adding handlers to the logger somewhere?

Comment: You are setting up logging every time you instantiate the class? Logging should be setup separately. Class instances should just log and let the caller decide what should be logged where.

Comment: tdelaney, do you have an example of Class instances letting the caller decide what should be logged?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a handler to the parent class each time you construct a class instance using this line:

```
self.logger.addHandler(console)
```

So if you do something like:

```
for _ in range(x):
    SubClass1()
some_operation_with_logging()
```

You should be seeing `x` messages, since you just added `x` handlers to the logger by doing `x` calls to parent's `__init__`.

You don't want to be doing that, make sure you add a handler **only once**!
You can access a logger's list of handlers using: `logger.handlers`.

---

Also, *if* you're using the same logger in both classes (named `"TDOA"`) by using this line in both:

```
self.logger=logging.getLogger('TDOA')
```

Make sure you either synchronize the logger instantiation, or use separate loggers.

---

### What I use:

Instead of having a private logger for each instance, you probably want a logger for all of them, or to be more precise - for the class itself:

```
class ClassWithLogger(object):
    logger = None
    def __init__(self):
        if not ClassWithLogger.logger:
            ClassWithLogger.logger = logging.getLogger("ClassWithLogger")
            ClassWithLogger.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
        # log using ClassWithLogger.logger ...
        # convenience:
        self.logger = ClassWithLogger.logger
```

And now you know `logger` is instantiated **once per class** (instead of once per instance), and all instances of a certain class use the same logger.

Comment: Reut, do you recommend a check before adding handlers then for every class that adds a handler?

I'm not using the same logger.  The other is "SatGeo."

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it; it still writes twice with that fix implemented.   :-(

Comment: can you add the parent, and both subclasses to the question? only need the lines that involve loggers

Comment: Made modifications above with the changes you recommended, hopefully providing more clarity.

Comment: @KurtPeters The problem is that: `console = logging.StreamHandler()` creates a new handler each time you instantiate the class. So you need to verify there is no stream handler in handlers (and not the exact object `console`!), or use the "trick" you're using in tdoa to set up the logger **once**.

Comment: I did a check of handlers for the loggers, and at the end of the cleanup of the last function call of the class, I do a `self.logger.handlers = []`. That also can work as a check at the beginning as well, so that handlers are not continually added for each call to the `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found a few links suggesting that submodules should take a logger as an input during the **init**:

```
def __init__ (self, pattern= None, action=None, logger = None):
    # Set up logging for the class
    self.log = logger or logging.getLogger(__name__)
    self.log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

Note: the nullhandler is added to avoid a warning if the user decides to not provide a logger.

Then, if you want to debug your submodule:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_level = logging.INFO
    log = logging.getLogger('cmdparser')
    log.setLevel(log_level)
    fh = logging.FileHandler('cmdparser.log')
    fh.setLevel(log_level)
    # create console handler with a higher log level
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(log_level)
    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    # formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add the handlers to the logger
    log.addHandler(fh)
    log.addHandler(ch)
    <myfunction>(pattern,action, log)
```

Then provide the log to the module at instantiation.

I hope this helps.